# Reduce paperclip attachment image by 37.5%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using paperclip in a Rails app to upload an image to S3. My has_attached_file in the model looks like this (left out some other details):

```
  has_attached_file :media,
                :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>", :two_x => "50%", :one_five_x => "37%", :one_x => "25%"},
```

This correctly saves 5 versions of the file, the original, thumb, two_x, one_five_x, and one_x. I'd like, however, for the one_five_x asset to be 37.5% of the image's original size. So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to do a decimal point.

How do I set a paperclip style to 37.5%?